# tkinter - font inconsistency between visual studio code debugging and command line

Tags: tkinter, visual-studio-code, python-3.6, linux-mint, xfce

I'm using **Visual Studio Code 1.31.0** to create a `Python GUI` using **`tkinter`**.

I'm using **`Linux Mint 19.1 xfce`**.

The problem here is when I run the `Main_form.py` using the traditional command line `python3 Main_form.py` I get this as my output:

[image: command line tkinter]

And when I use the `Debug > Start Debugging` option of `Visual Studio Code`, I get this output:

[image: debugging tkinter]

You can clearly see the difference in Font of the two GUI forms even though they use the same code. Pasting the relevant part of the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font
root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
myFont = Font(family="FreeSans", size=10, weight="bold")
```

As requested in the comments Visual Studio Code uses the command -

```
cd /home/zaid/Desktop/NISGUIPythonServer ; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" /usr/bin/python3 /home/zaid/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.1.0/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 43531 /home/zaid/Desktop/NISGUIPythonServer/Main_Form.py
```

Any reason on this inconsistency?

Comment: Your question doesn't include a question.

Comment: the title? font incons....

Comment: The title doesn't ask a question either, it just makes a statement. Are you asking why they are different? How to get one to look like the other? What have you done to debug this? Are you certain that the two methods you're using use the exact same python executable?

Comment: alright. Updated it as you requested.